# Admin login should ask credentiols while loging in

Tags: javascript, php, css, json

Please anybody could help me to find the solution for following,

.  Login with admin
    - Copy a link from the browser
    - Close the browser without logging out
    - Open a browser and paste the link

Expected:
  It should prompt to enter credentials.
  Actual:
  Its logging in without prompting for credentials

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried. If you have code, share that as well. It's very hard to answer your question in its current state.

Comment: Are you using cookie?

Comment: Try `session` variables, session variables expires once the browser is closed. Read more here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

Browser remember that you are logged because cookies. These cookies have expiration date. Cookies will be not deleted when you close the browser (only privacy tabs clear cookies). Try to sign out if you want to log out.